# What is the diference between static_cast<int>(var) and *(int*)&var?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, static-cast

OK so I tried doing this

```
 int b;
 char x = 'a';

//Case 1    
b = static_cast<int>(x); 
std::cout<<"B is : "<<b<<std::endl;

//Case 2
b = *(int*)&x;   
std::cout<<"B is changed as  :: "<< b <<std::endl;
```

Now I know that in case 2, first byte of `x` is reinterpreted to think that it is an integer and the bit pattern is copied into `b` which gives of some garbage and in case 1 it just converts the value from `char` to `int`.

Apart from that are there any differences between these two?

Comment: One is undefined behavior and the other is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first one just converts the value: `int b = x;` is the same as `int b = static_cast<int>(x);`.

The second case pretends that there is an `int` living at the place where in actual fact the `x` lives, and then tries to read that `int`. That's outright undefined behaviour. (For example, an `int` might occupy more space than a `char`, or it might be that the `char` lives at an address where no `int` can ever live.)

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd case is a C-style cast (as identified by bhuang3), but it's not the C-style equivalent to case 1.  That would be 
`b = (int)x;`.  And the C++ equivalent of case 2 would be `b = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&x);`  Either way you do it, case 2 is undefined behavior, because x occupies one byte, while forcibly reading an int's worth of data at x's address will either give you a segmentation fault (bus error on some systems) if it's not at a legal address for an `int`, or it will just read the next 3 bytes, whose values we don't know what they are.  Thus it reads "garbage" as you observed.

Comment: @phonetagger.....Case-2 can come handy in finding the byte ordering of a machine....

Comment: @noleptr - Yes, sort of.  But the other way around:  Read a byte at an int location.  As mentioned above, reading an int at a byte location may SEGV if it's not aligned on an int boundary.

Comment: @noleptr: Yes; but ONLY if you use an array of char that is at least as long as an integer (otherwise the code is broken). But that information is not that useful, any problem that requires you to know this(the byte order) has already been solved in a better way.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Are you sure that "better way" doesn't use a trick like this at its core?

Comment: @phonetagger: It probably does. But the trick has been abstracted for you in a functional well tested library. Or it is something built in-to the build environment so that is known correct and does not have a runtime cost.

Comment: @LokiAstari - "...in a functional well tested library."  Well, someone wrote that functional, well-tested library.  Probably noleptr in his spare time. :)

Comment: Probably the compiler vender. If recreating an already functional wheel that has been available for over 2 decades is what you like doing then fine.

Comment: @LokiAstari - There are a few places in my company's product that has to worry about byte order.  We process data that comes from a variety of hardware platforms, and our code itself is built for some of those same platforms.  To write portable code that operates in mixed byte-order environments, it's often necessary to play tricks like this to figure out the host's byte order.  We write those libraries that do that magic!

Comment: @phonetagger: You probably should be using the built-in ones.

Comment: @LokiAstari - OK, lemme know what you think we should be using.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/htonl.html They are available on all platforms and are the optimal way for implementing this conversion.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Those convert between host byte order (which may be LE or BE) and network byte order (BE).  That won't help much if we need to convert from LE to BE on a BE host.

Comment: ...and anyway, using htonl() and its friends would be adding a thin abstraction onto what isn't all that complex in the first place.

Comment: Why would you convert from LE on BE host. Where do you get the data from? That show a lack of correct design. Your data is either in byte order of your host or the byte order of a common storage format (which is most likely NBO). You should never be explicitly converting from one to the other.

Comment: We can't control the byte order of the data we get.  It comes from a variety of sources (not within our company).  It does not come over the network (at least not directly).  But we know it (the order).  We just have to know the byte order of the host in order to know if we need to swap the incoming data in order to treat it as larger data types.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Surely you'd agree that there must be some situation out there, perhaps writing a cross-compiler, where byte order must be explicitly converted?  What makes you think you're not talking to someone whose company writes cross compilers?

Comment: NO. Don't agree. That's why nowadays they have modular compilers that will use the host specific assembler to do the work. The situation you expound here is not going to occur when designed correctly (PS. I was a compiler writer).

Comment: @LokiAstari - OK, so then the host-specific cross assembler does it.  Still, somewhere, it's got to be done.  You just can't convince me otherwise.  And since it's got to be done somewhere, someone has to know how to do it right at that level.

Comment: @LokiAstari - Our product reads in files that contain raw binary data in their own hosts' byte order, processes that data, and writes it back out in a new raw binary file of that same host's byte order.  But the host on which the processing is done may not match the byte order of the file that's being processed.

Comment: @LokiAstari - ...and we don't have the luxury of telling the provider & ultimate consumer of this source data & destination data to provide it in a fixed byte order.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `static_cast` doesn't provide runtime checks, which is used if you know that you refer to an object of a specific type.
2. The seconde case actually is `c-style cast`